# Place an image over the object in Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to place an image in a part of the object, i have tried to do:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(10, 10, 0);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('models/packagin/place.png')});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

mesh.position.set(10, 5, 0);

material.map.needsUpdate = true; //ADDED

OBJ.traverse(function (child) {

    if (child.name !== '') {
        OBJ.add(mesh)
    }
});
```

The new object is placed over the primary object but is a flat rectangle

[image]

How can I put it so that it is part of the other object?

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: I believe your question doesn't fully explain what you're trying to do. What is the desired result? You created a box with 10 width, 10 height, and 0 depth, so you are going to get a flat rectangle.

Comment: yes but i want insert the image directly in the object map, i don't want replace the map, i want add the image in the map even if he already has another image. The screenshot is wrong.

Comment: So you want one texture on the mesh, then add another texture on top of the first one without replacing the first one?

Comment: yes, here is the problem, looking at the screenshot I would like the yellow image (with those dimensions) to be part of the object.
Instead, the background that already exists must remain

Comment: i have try to do:
if (child.name !== '') {
 var clone_material = child.material[0].clone();
 clone_material.map = texture;
 child.material = clone_material;
}
but this code only replace the material map

Comment: If you want two textures, one overlapping the other, you'll have to write your own custom shader, since Three.js materials only allow for one map at a time. Or you could clone the OBJ on top of the original, and add a texture with transparency on the clone.